# Logmein unable to connect to network adapter

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, hamachi, logmein

For some reason, when I started up Logmein Hamachi today (I use it to host Minecraft servers easily when only a few people will play at a time), I could not launch my Minecraft server because it threw "cannot bind to port". I would have put this on gaming, but when I looked at Hamachi, it displayed a yellow triangle sign next to my friend's name (he was the only person on at the time, but I believe the problem would have applied to any contacts). When I opened up the details it said that the details of the VPN error were under settings, and there it said " network adapter error: Failed to connect to the network adapter. Peer is not accessible via VPN."

What could I have done that started this? I am on Windows 8, Envy, but Hamachi has always worked in the past. I re-installed Hamachi, restarted it, turned it off and on, and then restarted my computer, to no avail. How can I fix this, what started it, and how can I avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup a DNS with No-IP, or any other solution. Forward the 25565 port. Execute the .jar and you are ready to go. You need to give the DNS to your friends, uninstall Hamachi it will mess up everything